# Phase noise definition

Tags: noise, phase

I have some problem with understanding the phase noise definition formula.
please see this image:

[image]

I can't understand the paragraph that I show ? near it. How is it possible to get phase noise > 0 dB when the power is less than carrier signal?

In this image. what is difference between A.11 and A.12 formula? and how does A.12 cause "This redefinition is intended to avoid difficulties in the use" ?

[image]

1. This definition breaks down when the mean squared phase deviation, How is it possible?